# Is there a way to test a failed tire to make sure it meets specs?

Tags: tires

I had to get a car tire replaced today, because it was punctured by a rock.  Not a particularly sharp rock either, just your average, everyday rock.  It went straight through a rain groove.

I bought the car two days ago--it doesn't even have 400 miles on it.  I am either astronomically unlucky (which might be possible, I'll grant) or there is something not right about that tire.

I didn't have the shop dispose of the tire yet, because I want to know if there's some way I can get it tested to see if the tire is defective somehow.  Can I send it someplace?  What sort of defects could the tire have had?

Comment: So this was a brand new car?  I doubt that getting the tire checked out (especially if you have to ship it) will be cost effective?  What's the end goal?

Comment: Yes, brand new car, driven three times.  The goal is peace of mind--like I said, the odds are pretty crazy for the tire to blow so quick.  I want to make sure there's no defect/degradation/other factor that might affect the other 3 tires.

Comment: I know this isn't related to what you're asking, but couldn't you get the tire patched or plugged?

Comment: I would imagine there would be fee's involved in this.  I worked at quite a few shops back in the day and I've never heard of a service that would test the manufacturing quality of tire before.

Comment: How much are you willing to spend on this?

Comment: What did the dealer say? If you've just spent thousands on a car, they might be inclined to help out.

Answer (score 7):

Tires have a warranty on them from the factory. Its quite possible the rock went thru the tire, because of a defective steel belt underneath. And the tire company would be responsible for that manufacturing defect.

- Remember the warranty on the tires is not covered by the car company, it's covered by the tire manufacturer.
- Normally rocks just don't go through tires like that.
- Check your tire warranty papers that come with the new car, in the glove box.
- I'd let the tire rep look at it. You want the regional service rep for that company, not a person who just works at your local tire shop.   Ask politely at your local shop, but insist on the tire being reviewed by the regional rep.   The regional rep will be a direct employee of Goodyear, Firestone or one of the other tire companies. Frankly those guys are happy to correct issues with real customers and find ways to improve their own manufacturing processes.
- They have a procedure, and that procedure is written down.
- Check your tire warranty pamphlet. Just follow the instructions inside.

Good luck with it...

Comment: good one.  tried to think of a good answer but couldn't come up with one.  this is a good answer  +1